# Spring Boot doesn't create Service bean and bypasses it's activity in Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Project structure:

[image]

Here is the repository (no class exceeds 20 lines of code): https://github.com/MoskovchenkoD/spring5-jokes

Here is the problem: Service implementation isn't used, and 'joke' attribute doesn't get printed on the page (just '123'). Controller's @RequestMapping method is simply ignored or bypassed.
How to fix it? I was following a step-by-step video from generating a project at start.spring.io to launching it.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yet another childish error =(

I moved the Application class one level up and now it works fine.

[image]